# python 2.5.4 with pyTTS 3.0 -- ValueError: "SAPI" not supported

Tags: python, sapi

I've been using python 2.5.4 with pyTTS 3.0 on Windows 7, using MS Speech SDK 5.1. It's been working great for well over a year. However, yesterday, two things happened almost simultaneously. MS did one of those updates that caused my system to reboot while I wasn't looking. And I ran out of disk space almost simultaneously. After clearing up some space, pyTTS no longer works. I get a "SAPI" not supported error message. From the command prompt I do the following:

```
>python
Python 2.5.4 (r254:67916, Dec 23 2008, 16:10:54) [MSC v.1310 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pyTTS
>>> x = pyTTS.Create()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python25\Lib\site-packages\pyTTS\__init__.py", line 28, in Create
    raise ValueError('"%s" not supported' % api)
ValueError: "SAPI" not supported
```

I have reinstalled:
python 2.5.4,
python windows extensions w32com,
pyTTS 3.0,
Microsoft Speech SDK 5.1,
Microsoft-English-TTS-51.
I have rebooted after each of these.
But it still doesn't work and I still get the same error message.

Any suggestions are much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: You could spend a lot of time tracing and trying to figure out what went wrong.  Or you could uninstall and reinstall the SDK package, and if that doesn't fix the problem, python itself.

Comment: I clarified what was re-installed. See posting.

Answer (score 0):

The python pyTTS module simply uses the Microsoft SAPI COM objects, and if these are no longer registered the module fails in the manner you see.

Re-installing the [Microsoft Speech SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10121) *should* fix this for you.

Answer (score 0):

So thanks to the contributors for their suggestions. But here's what worked. pyTTS imports win32com. And win32com keeps a cache pickled in a file under Pythonxx/Lib/site-packages/win32com/gen_py/dicts.dat. Somehow, that file dicts.dat got corrupted. And somehow, when reinstalling win32com, that file didn't get blown away. Probably because it was being grabbed by python running somewhere in the background while the installation was going on. I didn't stop to investigate further. Anyway, when properly removed and win32com reinstalled, then pyTTS resumed working. --